# How to delete an item of a list if it contains a substring in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of Windows paths:

```
pathsList = ['...', '...', '...', ...]
```

I need to exclude the paths that contain a substring (name of a folder).

```
substring = "folderName"
```

I've tried something like this:

```
for item in pathsList :
    if substring in item:
        pathsList.remove(item)
```

It kinda worked for, like 2 or 3 elements of the list. It didn't search all the elements of the list. Can anyone help me understand why or find another solution? I've searched a lot and tried many solutions here on StackOverflow but nothing worked for me. I must be doing something wrong for this code to work only for a couple of items.

Comment: `pathsList = [item for item in pathsList if substring not in item]`

Comment: It worked, thanks... I've tried a lot of things and got strange results, but this worked just fine! Thank you so much

Comment: modifying a list you're iterating over lead to weird result, is better to make a new one with the desire items

Comment: @CatarinaRibeiro read the linked duplicate (at the top), the accepted answer has a pretty clear explanation of what is going on, but essentially, when you remove an item from a list, it will skip the next item in the iteration because the indices shift